ScyllaDB cqlsh JDBC Driver with DBeaver
I am trying to connect through ScyllaDB using a third party JDBC driver. I am largely referencing here: https://java-driver.docs.scylladb.com/stable/index.html#

Going to maven.com here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.scylladb and grabbing the java-driver-core-shaded
Open up DBeaver

Database > Driver Manager > New > Library > Add file
Pick the downloaded shaded .jar file
Go back to Settings tab
Populate accordingly
Hit ok


Then go back to Database > New connection

Put the JDBC info in accordingly jdbc:cassandra://hostname:9042



However, I am getting the following error:
Can't create driver instance
  Error during driver instantiation
  Error during driver instantiation
    com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession.<init>()
    com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession.<init>()


Furthermore, if I try to use com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver this driver, I am able to inspect my schemas, but anytime I query a table, I get:
SQL Error: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query

Has anyone actually done this successfully?

A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

The Java driver is a client that exclusive uses the Cassandra native CQL binary protocol. It is completely different from JDBC-compliant drivers so you won't be able to use it with DBeaver.
The cassandra-jdbc-wrapper from ING is a wrapper for the Cassandra Java driver that is JDBC-compliant that works with Apache Cassandra 2.1+, DataStax Enterprise 5.0+ and DataStax Astra DB (see the compatibility matrix).
In theory it should work however it is not officially tested on ScyllaDB so you'll have to do some testing of your own.
The NoNodeAvailableException indicates that the driver is not able to reach your cluster at all so you need to make sure that there's network connectivity between your laptop/machine where DBeaver is installed and your ScyllaDB instance.
One important thing to add is that you must specify BOTH (1) the keyspace name, and (2) the local DC. The JDBC URL should look something like this:
jdbc:cassandra://myhost:9042/ks_name?localdatacenter=DC1

For more info, see the JDBC driver and connection string page. Cheers!

Bingo. Thanks for the help. And yeah definitely move it to DBA Stack Exchange, I just figured it was not exactly an "admin" question, but c'est la vie. Yeah what bit me was the localdatacenter query param. For any others, I found mine by doing SELECT data_center FROM system.local;
